# "celebrate on your father's victory"

Tags: meaning

I playing a MMORPG browser game. In this game we have village and warriors to fight each other.

I have an enemy that he attacked me several times and he was successful in his attacks. So I came with a payback and attacked his village. The result of this attack is still unknown(it takes time for troops to reach his village). At this situation he mailed me:

> now you attacking me?
>
> celebrate on your father's victory?

What's the meaning of "celebrate on your father's victory?"

Is it an expression?

Is it an offensive expression?

I google it but couldn't find anything.

Comment: This is not a phrase I have ever heard.  I suspect the individual who sent you the message was not speaking in his/her native tongue.

Comment: @Lumberjack Unfortunately I can't ask him about his/her native tongue (because we are serious enemies), Have you any opinion about the meaning ?

Comment: It seems simply that he is not a native speaker. What he says is clearly understandable but not idiomatic, so that it is clear to any listener that English is not his first language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it involves ungrammatical English and as non-native-language gamespeak is further removed from standard English than even song lyrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take:

He **plays the superior**, gives himself airs, **calls himself "your father."**

He asks you whether you don't want to accept defeat already and celebrate his/"your father's" victory.

Answer (score 1):

It is not offensive- he is asking if you are celebrating your father's victory.
You celebrate a victory, not celebrate "on" a victory. The reason for his mistake is probably that there are other expressions such as "on your birthday..." You celebrate your birthday, but you also celebrate on your birthday, which means you celebrate on that day. But, you do not celebrate on a victory, you celebrate the victory.

Comment: Are you saying the preposition "on" is unneeded? maybe he hasn't proper troops so he concluded that as a fail. In this situation I think I can celebrate on a victory. am I right?

Comment: You could celebrate on the day of a victory, but you don't celebrate "on" a victory. It just sounds like a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion:

> He is mocking you (by asking)-
>
> You attacking **ME**??
>
> Do you want to celebrate **my** (your father's) victory?